# String return value does not get assigned within for-loop in Rust

Tags: string, for-loop, rust, variable-assignment

Given this code-snippet:

```
pub fn verse(start_bottles: i32) -> String {
    let mut song_template: String = "%1 of beer on the wall, %2 of beer.\n%3, %4 of beer on the wall.\n".to_string();

    match start_bottles {
        0 => lyrics_no_bottles(&mut song_template),
        1 => lyrics_one_bottle(&mut song_template),
        2 => lyrics_two_bottles(&mut song_template),
        _ => lyrics_more_bottles(&mut song_template, start_bottles)
    }
    song_template
}

pub fn sing(first: i32, last: i32) -> String {
    let mut song: String = "".to_string();
    for num in (8..6).rev() {
        song = verse(1);
    }
    song
}
```

As I output `verse(1)` it works fine - the tested string appears and is complete. But when I assign the result of `verse(1)` to the `String` binding `song`, `song` seems to be empty? I do not understand this behaviour.

Comment: Just a comment about your code, unrelated to the question: you can remove those explicit `String` type annotations, when your right-hand-side already is a string (which it is in case of using `to_string()`).

Comment: I keep it for readability...I dont like inference much in every case...want to see the type at all times

Comment: I can completely understand that, but it is pretty important to settle on one coding style within the community such that everyone can quickly read everyone else's code, even if it feels wrong for newcomers of a language. But this is nothing to settle in the SO comment section :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's not how ranges work; it's got nothing to do with the strings.  If you run the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 8..6 {
        println!("a: {}", i);
    }
    for i in (8..6).rev() {
        println!("b: {}", i);
    }
    for i in 6..8 {
        println!("c: {}", i);
    }
    for i in (6..8).rev() {
        println!("d: {}", i);
    }
}
```

You get the following output:

```
c: 6
c: 7
d: 7
d: 6
```

Ranges **only** count up, they never count down.  `rev` reverses the order of the sequence you give it; it doesn't turn an empty sequence into a non-empty one.